# Prove that for every subset X of a metric space, Cl Cl X = Cl X.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Note: This is not homework help.  This is simply to help me understand more about the topic of computational topology.

Does anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: Under some definitions of $\text{Cl}\ X$, this is very simple. For other definitions it takes a little bit of work. So, what is your definition of $\text{Cl}\ X$?

Comment: The proof largely depends on the definition of closure you are using.

Comment: I tend to think there's someone who knows how to prove this.

Comment: Closure: set containing every point in X and every limit point of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a limit point of $\text{cl}(X).$ We want to show that $p$ is in $X$ or is a limit point of $X,$ so let $r>0.$ Then there is a point $q\ne p$ in $\text{cl}(X),\ d(p,q)=:s<r.$ Either, $q\in X,$ then we are finished, or $q$ is a limit point of $X.$ In that case, the ball $B_{r-s}(q)$ of radius $r-s$ is contained in $B_r(p)$ and intersects $X,$ so $B_r(p)$ intersects $X$ for any $r>0.$ This means $p$ is in $X$ or is a limit point of $X.$

Comment: This seems thorough and makes sense to me.  I wouldn't have thought of using the Ball, but that is a big point of what we are learning in class, to use the defined structures for further proofs (actually in this case, would it be a half ball?  I'll have to go back and see and think about it).  Big thanks, will study thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

$cl(X)$ is a set containing the points of $X$ and its limit points so it is a closed set.

$cl(X)$ is the smallest closed set containing $X$, in any metric space, as any closed set containing $X$ contains all points of $X$ and limit points of $X$, and so will be a superset of $cl(X)$.

Closer of a closet set is itself, as it contains all its limit point in itself. 
So it shall be the smallest closed set containing it.

Now $cl(X)$ is a closed set. So $cl(cl(X))$ will be closed and equal to $cl(X)$. Thus $cl(cl(X)) = cl(X)$. Hence the proof.